# Creating Power Planes under USB lines

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design, routing

I have another question about PCB layout. I'm designing using this guide:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sllu149e/sllu149e.pdf?ts=1618900105338&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

I don't find nothing about problems between power planes and USB traces. Will it be problems if I create a power plane under the component and USB traces? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Have you calculated what is the effect to trace impedance? Usually USB pair is routed on top of reference plane, which usually is a ground plane, but with care, you can change the reference plane to supply plane. The trace width would at least change whether you have a reference plane or no plane at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB 2.0 interfaces up to 12 Mbit/s (full speed) won't have problems if you put a ground plane beneath or not, provided you draw the PCB traces D+ and D- of the same length and short: the shorter the better.

In 2016 I designed a PCB with NXP LPC2388 microcontroller which has a USB 2.0 interface running at 12 Mbit/s.

The length of the PCB traces were 18 mm.

Both host (USB flash drive) and device (removable hard disk) interfaces worked perfectly.